# jQuery val() Method on a Custom Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, oop, user-defined

I have an object called ValueBox that I created like this:

```
function ValueBox(params) {
   ...
   $.extend(true, this, $('/* some HTML elements */'));
   ...
   var $inputBox = $('input[type=text]', this);
   ...
   this.val = function(newValue) {
      if(typeof newValue == "number") {
         $inputBox.val(newValue);
         $inputBox.change();
      } else {
         return parseFloat($inputBox.val());
      }
   }
}
```

I have a change event on a particular ValueBox instance which fires whenever the `$inputBox` changes, but the change callback function is unable to use the val() method in my class. I assume that by using `$(this).val()` that I'm calling the jQuery val() method, which of course wouldn't work. Is it possible to access the val() method that I defined?

Comment: "unable to use" means what exactly (for clarification). it can't access it? did you try calling the val method from firebug? it certainly looks public to me.

Comment: My understading is that in the change handler, the keyword "this" refers to the element itself and not the object I created. If I wrap that like $(this), it simply uses the normal jQuery object instead of mine.

Comment: Oh! ok, i think i know a way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$inputBox.change()`, pass it the `ValueBox` object. Then call `val` on that. That way, you won't have to worry about scoping problems within jQuery controls.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really like it, but I suppose it's the only way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yeah, jQuery applies the functions with its own scope, and you need some way to change it, without breaking the internal code of jQuery. therefore, you need to pass the object.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.yourpluginscope.originalVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.extend({
    val: function (value) {
        if (/* detect your plugin element */)
        {
            if (value == undefined)
                return /* getter */;
            return $.fn.yourpluginscope.originalVal.call(/* setter */, value);
        }
        return $.fn.yourpluginscope.originalVal.call(this, value);
    }
});
```

Proper way to extends "native" jQuery method

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in extending val() for your plugin, you can try something like the following:

Let us assume that you have set and attribute "value" in the outermost element of your plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ val: function(newValue) {
    if (newValue == null) {
        return $(this).attr("value");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("value", newValue);        
    }
} 
});
```

If the id of my plugin instance is myValueBox then I would be able to use val in the following manner:

$("#myValueBox").val()

It worked for me but I am not sure if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try something like that

```
function ValueBox(params) {
   ...
   $.extend(true, this, $('/* some HTML elements */'));
   ...
   this.inputBox = $('input[type=text]', this);
   ...
}

ValueBox.prototype.val = function(newValue) {
    if(typeof newValue == "number") {
        this.inputBox.val(newValue);
        this.inputBox.change();
    } else {
        return parseFloat(this.inputBox.val());
    }
};

// then this should work
var test = new ValueBox();
test.val(123);
```

In prototype you define public methods, all that is in `ValueBox` function is private;

Comment: `this.val = function...` is most certainly not private.

Comment: if it were `function val() {...}`, then it would have been a private function.